# HTML custom tag for my consent cookie banner - is not display on the website GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

So I am trying to setup a cookie consent banner and trigger Analytics when the user accept the service. This is my second attempt doing this(first time I failed miserable) and I am not sure if I am missing something, because in the research I did, looks pretty much straight forward but for some reason is not working for me.

This is the way my configuration looks on the GTM dashboard. So my Tag manager, where i have for now only two tags, one for the banner, that is a HTML custom Tag and the second that is for the Google Analytics.

This is the way my Custom HTML looks like.

[image]

When I try to run the GTM preview mode this is what I get. For me it's not clear, it says the Tag is triggered, however is not displayed on the preview mode, nor on the website
[image]

I also need to mention, that I placed the container on the website, and my code looks as follows(for now), also this is a SPA I also don't know if can be something related to that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // create dataLayer
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    // set „denied" as default for both ad and analytics storage,
    gtag("consent", "default", {
      ad_storage: "denied",
      analytics_storage: "denied",
      wait_for_update: 2000 // milliseconds to wait for update
    });

    // Enable ads data redaction by default [optional]
    gtag("set", "ads_data_redaction", true);
  </script>

  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script type="text/javascript">(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
      }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
  <title>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
  <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0"
      style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

  <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled.
        Please enable it to continue.</strong>
  </noscript>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>

</html>
```

I am not sure if I need to provide another type of information, so please let me know.

** EDIT **

Below the custom HTML Tag script, where the first script is just to include the main SDK script.

```
<script>
  var cookie = document.createElement("script");
      cookie.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://www.mywebsite.com/redesign-scripts/vendor/udg-uc-sdk.min.js"
    );
   cookie.setAttribute("id", "xxxxxxxx");
   document.head.appendChild(cookie);
  </script>


    <script>
        var GlobalConsent = GlobalConsent || {};

        //Activate new modal style
        GlobalConsent.NewModalSDK = true;

        //Set language
        GlobalConsent.Language = 'en';


        //Set privacy shield content
        window.ucPrivacyShield = {
            bgimage: 'https://linktoimage.com/image.jpg',
            consentunavailable: {
                text: 'Die zur Anzeige notwendigen Inhalte konnten nicht geladen werden. Falls Sie einen AdBlocker verwenden, überprüfen Sie bitte dessen Einstellungen.'
            },
            consentservice: {
                headline: 'Hinweis zur Datenverarbeitung',
                text: 'Auf unserer Website stellen wir Inhalte von ###SERVICE### bereit. Um diese Inhalte zu sehen, müssen Sie der Datenverarbeitung durch ###SERVICE### zustimmen.',
                buttons: {
                    consent: {
                        label: 'Zustimmmen'
                    },
                    privacy: {
                        label: 'Hinweise zum Datenschutz',
                        link: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/de/privacy/'
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        //Wait for UC SDK loading
        window.addEventListener('ucReady', function (e) {


            //Check Youtube & Vimeo iFrame consent
            window.ucPrivacyShield.checkConsent({
                mapContainer: document.getElementById('youtube-vimeo-iframe'),
                processorId: ['_xxxxx', '-xxxxx'],
                timeoutVar: {},
                callbacks: {
                    success: function () {
                        var iFrame = document.getElementById('youtube-vimeo-iframe').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
                        iFrame.src = iFrame.dataset.src;
                    },
                    p: undefined
                }
            });

        }, false);
    </script>
```

*U P D A T E

I was wondering if someone else have any idea about this, I still don't manage to solve the issue, And I  was wondering if it related that the app is rendered client site, and someone when the google tag is trying to append the DOM it is still not there, I tried by wrapping the append inside a "onload" function, but did not worked as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you check localStorage and cookies to ensure, that you don't have preexisting settings.
The banner is only displayed, when there are no preexisting settings in your web storage. Since there are "consents-initialized" dataLayer events displayed in your screenshot, this could be possible.

Comment: Hi, thank you Ramon, if I checked the tab application, on the browser explorer and under cookies, everything is empty. As I mentioned before don't think that is even doing something, because the script file is not being include on the head or any other part of the rendered html, so make sense, however I don't know why ...

Comment: Did you get this resolved?